# canvas drawImage loading big image

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

i am draw some image on canvas its looks like this[image: This image looks good and i am storeing into array]
Now i am trying to reload same image into the canvas,its look like this [image]
This is my code

```
var ctx = element.childNodes[i + 1].children[0].firstElementChild;
if (ctx.getContext) {
  ctx = ctx.getContext('2d');
  var img1 = new Image();
  img1.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img1, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  }
}
```

I tried to set canvas height and width to the image but now working

```
var ctx = element.childNodes[i + 1].children[0].firstElementChild;
if (ctx.getContext) {
  ctx = ctx.getContext('2d');
  var img1 = new Image();
  img1.onload = function() {
    img1.width = ctx.canvas.width;
    img1.height = ctx.canvas.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img1, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  }
}
```

After that  tried like this,image loading correctly but trying to redraw image again curser some where else and drawing some other position

```
var ctx = element.childNodes[i + 1].children[0].firstElementChild;
if (ctx.getContext) {
  ctx = ctx.getContext('2d');
  var img1 = new Image();
  img1.onload = function() {
    ctx.canvas.width = img1.width;
    ctx.canvas.height = img1.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img1, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: To help you out, we'll need to be able to run your code. Create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in which we can run your code. Look into creating a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) so we can run your code on this page.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Please find Link https://jsfiddle.net/29x7djo1/1/

Comment: I took a look and created this result [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0tu9fLa/). You were missing some CSS to scale your canvas appropriately. And the `<img>` tag was stretching the screen as well, so hide it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) needs 5 parameters in this scenario. The first one the image, which you have, but the other 4 are the x position, y position, width and height.

Using `drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height)` draws the image in the top-left corner.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const image = new Image();
image.src = 'http://www.fillmurray.com/g/600/300';
image.onload = () => {
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
};
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Also add some CSS to make sure that the `<canvas>` element itself it sized appropriately.

```
canvas {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Emiel Zuurbier , Same i am added but no use.  ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);